# Tizen TV WebAPI Overlay

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I'm trying to create an application that will show some info over the current screen in Tizen (for TV), using the WebAPI.
The main idea is to create a vertical bar on the side that will be transparent and showing some text in overlay with the screen. 
I have actually not succeeded in any type of transparency with the screen in the background. The example given [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/pip-picture-in-picture/showing-pip-overlays) (OverlayPiP link) is showing all white screen and the buttons do not change anything in spite of actually being called (I can see that on the screen).

I am using Tizen SDK 3.0 (which also allegedly supports OS 2.4) with Tizen Studio 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented exactly that. If you already use WebAPI, why not just overlay a transparent DIV over your content and then display the info there?

The way I solved this, was by having DIVs holding content (such as images, videos, websites, etc) in the background while placing a DIV on button press in the foreground. The latter is semi-transparent and updated asynchronously, whenever all info is collected from the system.

The API I used was `b2bapis.b2bcontrol`, though it may or may not be available to you, depending on your partnership lebel with SAMSUNG.

TL;DR:

Collect the info you need to display, then place it on a semi-transparent DIV and update asynchronously via callback.

Comment: Could you give me an example? The docs are not quite helpful. I've tried putting the screen in the background (with the 'BEHIND' parameter for `tizen.tvwindow.show` ) and then the transparent body with a non-transparent div but there was no effect. When I put 100% screen size, I either saw the web page or I saw the screen, no overlay.